# pythone 3 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: list, dictionary, integer, typeerror, slice

> import action_program_with_lists_and_dictionaries_logo
> import replit
> print(action_program_with_lists_and_dictionaries_logo.logo)
>
> switch = True
>
> bidding_log = []
> def add_new_bid(name, bid):
> new_bidder = {}
> new_bidder["name"] = user_name
> new_bidder["bid"] = user_bid
> bidding_log.append(new_bidder)
>
> def find_highest_bidder(bidding_record):
> highest_bid = 0
> winner = " "
> for bidder in bidding_record:
> print(bidder)
> bid_amount = bidding_record[bidder]
> if bid_amount > highest_bid:
> highest_bid = bid_amount
> winner = bidder
> print(f "The winner is {winner} with a bid of {highest_bid}")
>
> while
> switch:
>
> user_name = input("What is your name?: ")# keyDictionary
> user_bid = int(input("What is your bid?: "))# valueDictionary
> add_new_bid(name = user_name, bid = user_bid)
>
> stop_button = input("Do you want to continue bidding? type yes, if not type no")
> if stop_button == "no":
> switch = False
> find_highest_bidder(bidding_log)
> elif stop_button == "yes":
> replit.clear()
>
> Hello all,
> Please be kind and have a look on my code, i have a problem ,,pythone 3 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict", at def find_highest_bidder, is the break point when i am trying to pass the value 100 from bidding_record[bidder], any ideas how i can fix this?
> (apologies if is something obvious, i am a noobie :)

Comment: You may want to format your code and make it *readable* first.  (using the backticks )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.